# Mongoshell Giving Error Code 18 on Login Attempt MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I host my database with Mongolab (MongoDB hosting service). They recently (about a month ago) updated the MongoDB processes to 3.0. Since then, whenever I try to login using mongoshell, this happens:

```
mongo ds012345.mongolab.com:12345/mydb123 -u user123 -p pass123
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: ds012345.mongolab.com:12345/mydb123
2015-11-08T10:00:12.356-0800 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1292 exception: login failed
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. I first thought the problem was a version one (pretty sensible, I think), so I updated from the other 2.x version I was using to 2.6.11. According to MongoDB documentation, that should be compatible with 3.x.
2. I tried passing other arguments to the authentication string (like --authenticationDatabase admin). Didn't work.
3. Checked my credentials (i.e., usern+pass) and settings via the GUI interface available on Mongolab's site. There are no apparent problems.

Please help! I need to use the shell...

Comment: Have you tried using a 3.0.x version of the mongo shell? MongoLab's 3.0 databases use SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication, which is not supported by the 2.6.x mongo shell.

Comment: I am so embarrassed... That did it! I had to jump through a lot of hoops to get 3.0.x since Fedora's package manager (yum) doesn't seem to have it atm. I ended up downloading all of the packages from https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/6/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/RPMS/ and then doing yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ./Downloads/mongodb-org-* .  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was as pneumee suggested.

I just had to update to 3.0.x. I will document how this was done on Fedora 20 for future generations:

I had to jump through a lot of hoops to get 3.0.x since Fedora's package manager (yum) doesn't seem to have it atm. I ended up downloading all of the packages from repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/6/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/RPMS and then doing

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ./mongodb-org-*
```

That was all!